# Can double slashes on comments produce unexpected errors?

Tags: javascript, comments, slash

I need to know if double `//` slashes on the URL comment could produce errors:

```
function jsFunction(){
    //http://google.com
    var str="...";
}
```

**<sup>Other than syntax-highlighting-related errors</sup>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//` are single line comments, anything after it on the same line will be commented out, even more `/` characters.

`/*` is used to begin a multi-line comment. The next `*/` will end the multi-line comment. This could be an issue if you try comment out a regular expression:

```
/**
var foo = /.*/g
 */
```